# How to get contact's number when the name is known?

Tags: android

Right now, I'm writing an app that will access the user's contact information. My goal right now is to allow the user to pick someone from their contacts list to assign as their "Guardian". This is how I'm accessing the contacts:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManageGuardian.class);
                    i.putExtra("guardian_name", name);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Right now, I'm only getting the contact name. I want to get both the name, AND the phone number linked to that name. With that, I want to pass it into the next activity like I have done with the Intent. Is there a way for me to get both the name, and the phone number and pass it to the next activity? I can't figure it out right now, and am at a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using the ContactPicker Intent instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely suggest using a ContentPicker Intent and then starting another activity, passing in that data.  You have to make sure at first that you add the READ_CONTACTS uses permission to the manifest.  I was able to read the contacts with out it, but not pull their phone numbers.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

You also need to make sure you declare your second activity in the manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fuuuuuuuuu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fuuuuuuuuu.DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

In my example code, which works on a GenyMotion emulator with contacts populated, I have two activities, the main and the detail.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fuuuuuuuuu.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSelectContact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="Pick a Contact" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside activity_detail.xml, I have this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.fuuuuuuuuu.DetailActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside MainActivity.java, I have this code:

```
package com.example.fuuuuuuuuu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button _btnSelectContact;
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _btnSelectContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectContact);
    _btnSelectContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String hasPhoneNumberString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            Boolean hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNumberString) > 0;

            String phoneNumber = "";
            String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId;

            if (hasPhoneNumber) {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        selection,
                        null, null);

                // Only getting one here ultimately, you could handle multiples depending on type
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }
                phones.close();
            }

            cursor.close();

            Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            secondActivityIntent.putExtra("NAME", displayName);
            secondActivityIntent.putExtra("PHONE",  phoneNumber);
            startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Inside DetailActivity.java, I have this:

```
package com.example.fuuuuuuuuu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String displayName = extras.getString("NAME");
        String phoneNumber = extras.getString("PHONE");

        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

        name.setText(displayName);
        phone.setText(phoneNumber);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

It looks like you were most of the way there, you just needed to do the secondary cursor to get the phone numbers based on the user selected.  I just threw this project together quickly, but you could easily pass anything over to that second activity (User Id, Name, Phone, Email, etc) and then act upon it.